# Debugging PHP Mail() and/or PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm quite stuck with a problem sending mail from a PHP script.
Some data:

- Shared hosting, no SSH access, only hosting provider panel
- PHP version 5.2.5
- Last year I built a site which had no problems sending mail with the same hosting
- Let's say the domain is “domain.com” and my private address is “myaddress@mydomain.com” for anonimity's sake in the following code.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$to = "myaddress@mydomain.com";
$subject = "Hi";
$body = "Test 1\nTest 2\nTest 3";
$headers = 'From: info@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'errors-to: myaddress@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    echo("Message successfully sent");
} else {
    echo("Message sending failed");
}

require('class.phpmailer.php');
$message = "Hello world";
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->AddAddress("myaddress@mydomain.com", "Agos");
$mail->SetFrom("info@domain.com","My Site");
$mail->Subject = "Test Message";
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->Send();
?>
```

And here is what I get:

> Message sending failed
>   Could not instantiate mail function.

Which is baffling to say the least. Is there anything I can do to get at least some more meaningful errors? Why is code from the class showing up in my file?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It looks like the class.phpmailer.php file is corrupt. I would download [the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and try again.

I've always used phpMailer's SMTP feature:

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "localhost";
```

And if you need debug info:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                       // 1 = errors and messages
                       // 2 = messages only
```