# Send Email from PHP Script

Tags: php, email, send, phpmailer

I wrote some code to send an email from my PHP script using PHPMailer. For some reason, the scripts isn't sending the messages.

---

**Here Is My Code:**

```
<?php
require_once("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail=new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = "admin@zbrowntechnology.com";
$mail->Password = "PASSHERE";
$mail->SetFrom = "admin@zbrowntechnology.com";
$mail->AddAddress("zach@zbrowntechnology.com.com");
$mail->Subject = "Confirm Web Lock Registration!";
$mail->Body = "Please confirm your Web Lock Registration by clicking here!";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo 'Message was not sent.';
   echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message Sent!";
}
?>
```

**This Is The Error Echoed:**

```
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Message was not sent.Mailer error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

Comment: Are you getting your error message echoed and if so what is it?

Comment: Could you give more information on the problem?  Is it printing out the error message, or is it saying "Message Sent!" but you're still not receiving it?

Comment: @Zachary Brown: Never share your username and password publicly like this :)

Comment: You might want to remove or change the password in your question... Anyone viewing this can log in to your e-mail account right now.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43103/passwords-in-questions

Comment: Sorry about the password, I meant to remove it but just forgot. I removed from the question and changed the password on the account.

Comment: Your password is still in the revision history. You're probably just better off changing your password...before someone does it for you.

Comment: Which version of PHPMailer are you using? Your syntax (between setting attributes directly vs passing parameters to functions) is inconsistent with the examples I'm seeing on their site.

Comment: @yc, I've already changed the password on the account. I am using PHPMailer v5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using PHPMailer too, just tried your settings, and got the same error.
Here are my settings witch work for me (I show with ->> things witch you don't have, or are different for me)

```
$mail->PHPMailer = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
->> $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
->> $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //not ssl://smtp.gmail.com
$mail->Port = 465; etc...
```

Everything else is the same, except i don't use word wrap, but i checked, it's not causing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your error message might be caused by the firewall settings on your server.  This error message is commonly caused by a firewall blocking outgoing connections on the port.

You also should make sure that you have the openssl extension enabled.

Original Answer that you fixed:

You are sending to zach@zbrowntechnology.com.com which is not the address you want.

You need to remove the second .com and change it to zach@zbrowntechnology.com

Comment: Corrected it. Still the same problem.

Comment: I added some additional problems based on the error message you gave.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify *gmail* username and password because that is the what you are using in smtp settings:

```
$mail->Username = "email_address@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "yourgmailpassword";
```

Comment: The address is the username. The company uses Google Apps for email.

Answer (score 1):

As a general tip, try turning on debugging:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                       // 1 = errors and messages
                       // 2 = messages only
```

From SO: [Debugging PHP Mail() and/or PHPMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896280/debugging-php-mail-and-or-phpmailer)

Answer (score 0):

Just as a bit of advise you might also want to try using Zend_Mail, you can use this happily without having to go the whole MVC route and it is very informative