# email cant send with php

Tags: php, html, email

Hi I have downloaded Brushed responsive website template and php contact form wont work.

This is how contact form look like in the index.html file

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span9">
    <form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="_include/php/contact.php">
      <p class="contact-name">
        <input id="contact_name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" value="" name="name" />
      </p>
      <p class="contact-email">
        <input id="contact_email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" value="" name="email" />
      </p>
      <p class="contact-message">
        <textarea id="contact_message" placeholder="Your Message" name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
      </p>
      <p class="contact-submit">
        <a id="contact-submit" class="submit" href="#">Send Your Email</a>
      </p>
      <div id="response"></div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="span3">
    <div class="contact-details">
      <h3>Contact Details</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">hello@brushed.com</a></li>
        <li>(916) 375-2525</li>
        <li>
          Brushed Studio
          <br>
          5240 Vanish Island. 105
          <br>
          Unknow
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is how php look like

```
<?php

$admin_email = 'ozgurbabacan@gmail.com'; // Your Email
$message_min_length = 5; // Min Message Length


class Contact_Form{
    function __construct($details, $email_admin, $message_min_length){

        $this->name = stripslashes($details['name']);
        $this->email = trim($details['email']);
        $this->subject = 'Contact from Your Website'; // Subject 
        $this->message = stripslashes($details['message']);

        $this->email_admin = $email_admin;
        $this->message_min_length = $message_min_length;

        $this->response_status = 1;
        $this->response_html = '';
    }


    private function validateEmail(){
        $regex = '/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i';

        if($this->email == '') { 
            return false;
        } else {
            $string = preg_replace($regex, '', $this->email);
        }

        return empty($string) ? true : false;
    }


    private function validateFields(){
        // Check name
        if(!$this->name)
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter your name</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }

        // Check email
        if(!$this->email)
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter an e-mail address</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }

        // Check valid email
        if($this->email && !$this->validateEmail())
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter a valid e-mail address</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }

        // Check message length
        if(!$this->message || strlen($this->message) < $this->message_min_length)
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter your message. It should have at least '.$this->message_min_length.' characters</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }
    }


    private function sendEmail(){
        $mail = mail($this->email_admin, $this->subject, $this->message,
             "From: ".$this->name." <".$this->email.">\r\n"
            ."Reply-To: ".$this->email."\r\n"
        ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

        if($mail)
        {
            $this->response_status = 1;
            $this->response_html = '<p>Thank You!</p>';
        }
    }


    function sendRequest(){
        $this->validateFields();
        if($this->response_status)
        {
            $this->sendEmail();
        }

        $response = array();
        $response['status'] = $this->response_status;   
        $response['html'] = $this->response_html;

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}


$contact_form = new Contact_Form($_POST, $admin_email, $message_min_length);
$contact_form->sendRequest();

?>
```

Comment: "Won't work" isn't much use to us or you. What exactly isn't working? What errors, if any, are you getting? What do you expect to happen but what is actually happening? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896280/debugging-php-mail-and-or-phpmailer Use PHPMailer. It is more promising and easy to debug

Comment: And yet another php mail() problem

Comment: when i click to submit button it wont send email

Comment: so what is the response which gets echo back? is your webserver running PHP? do you have a mail agent installed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the method, default will use GET

```
method="POST"
```

In here

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="_include/php/contact.php">
```

End result would be

```
<form id="contact-form" method="POST" class="contact-form" action="_include/php/contact.php">
```

---

Make sure your action is pointing to the right folder as well.

Comment: thank you for the help. i've checked the action and its pointing to the right folder. i also add the method but still don't send an email. it does nothing :(