# Mail send error in bluehost with phpmailer

Tags: php

I am using php-mailer in bluehost server.
The mail->send does not give error but mail is not received at recipient's end.
I have no clue how can I debug.

Answer (score -2):

Look at this answer:

[Debugging PHP Mail() and/or PHPMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896280/debugging-php-mail-and-or-phpmailer)

You can debug with:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1);


$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                   // 1 = errors and messages
                   // 2 = messages only
```